# Divergence measure of two classifiers' performance?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, model-selection

I have two classifiers built with the same data. How can I measure divergence of these models?

I found something like [DIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_information_criterion) but I don't know how to calculate this in R?

Comment: By divergence, do you mean difference in performance?  Can you describe your training data?  Have you, for example, split the data into two, trained the models on half, and retained the other half for performance evaluation?

Comment: Actually I am not sure to measure divergence by comparing predictions for test data or comparing models but I've split data train and test sets and I've got predictions.

Comment: @RicardoCristianRamirez: Are you just comparing performance on the train and test sets? The workflow I typically use is to develop my classifier using cross-validation on the training set, and then, once I have a system I'm happy with, evaluate it on the hold-out test collection, to measure true performance. The difference between performance on the two sets is often taken to indicate the level of over-training on the training set.

Comment: @Kyle. I am also cross validating as you discussed but I want to compare how divergent two classifiers' predictions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I have the answer you're looking for. But hoping if I post something, it'll get more input for you.

I assume you don't want to use the true values of the observations (then you might want something like a NRI).
I don't think there is a set measure that I'm aware of. I'd be tempted to:

(1) Just treat it as inter-observer agreement. If using classification (%agreement/Kappa), or if using probabilities Bland-Altman methodology.
(2) Assuming probabilistic model, Try ROC+validation curve where you assume on of the models represents the true values might also be interesting.